# WP Booking Calendar reservations not showing in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, calendar

[I made a test page](http://iloveniceparis.com/fr/test/) to find out if I can use the booking calendar on a WordPress site. I imported a Google calendar, and everything works fine in Firefox. I tried to book some dates (in May) to check, and it works fine in Firefox. But in Chrome and Safari reservations are not showing. In the console I find an "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined".

I can't figure out what is causing this error and would appreciate any help!

Comment: Is it possible you are only logged in WP under Firefox?

Comment: No, I am not logged in.